# Minecraft server times out on every session

Tags: server, java, minecraft, timeout

I'm playing Minecraft Java Edition 1.17.1 on Ubuntu 21.10. My Minecraft server is Papermc version 1.17.1, using Ubuntu 20.04.3 server and openjdk 16).

Every time I join, the server times out after a few minutes. I tried to see if this happens on windows 10, and it didn't.

How can I stop times out from server?

P.S. On the error screen, it's just simply says "Connection lost, Timed out
[Screen Shot: The connection error just says "Timed Out"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRA7a.png)

Answer (score 0):

You tried to connect from Windows to the server on Linux or tried to start your server on windows?

I'm not sure that this is the same but try to check that Ubuntu allows you to accept the connection on your server port

Comment: According to the question, The client is connecting, but disconnects after a few minutes. When `ufw`, Ubuntu's firewall, blocks a connection, it reroutes it to dead air as soon as it is intercepted.